# A minimalistic smart array (container) class template

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming, containers

I've written a (array) container class template (lets call it *smart array*) for using it in the BREW platform (which doesn't allow many C++ constructs like STD library, exceptions, etc. It has a very minimal C++ runtime support); while writing this my friend said that something like this already exists in Boost called *MultiArray*, I tried it but the ARM compiler (RVCT) cries with 100s of errors. I've not seen `Boost.MultiArray`'s source, I've started learning templates only lately; template meta programming interests me a lot, although am not sure if this is strictly one that can be categorized thus.

So I want all my fellow C++ aficionados to review it ~ point out flaws, potential bugs, suggestions, optimizations, etc.; something like "you've not written your own *[Big Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)* which might lead to...". Possibly any criticism that will help me improve this class and thereby my C++ skills.

**Edit:** I've used `std::vector` since it's easily understood, later it will be replaced by a custom written vector class template made to work in the BREW platform. Also *C++0x* related syntax like `static_assert` will also be removed in the final code.

**smart_array.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdarg>
using std::vector;

template <typename T, size_t N>
class smart_array
{
    vector < smart_array<T, N - 1> > vec;

public:
    explicit smart_array(vector <size_t> &dimensions)
    {
        assert(N == dimensions.size());

        vector <size_t>::iterator it = ++dimensions.begin();
        vector <size_t> dimensions_remaining(it, dimensions.end());

        smart_array <T, N - 1> temp_smart_array(dimensions_remaining);
        vec.assign(dimensions[0], temp_smart_array);
    }

    explicit smart_array(size_t dimension_1 = 1, ...)
    {
        static_assert(N > 0, "Error: smart_array expects 1 or more dimension(s)");
        assert(dimension_1 > 1);

        va_list dim_list;
        vector <size_t> dimensions_remaining(N - 1);

        va_start(dim_list, dimension_1);
            for(size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
            {
                size_t dimension_n = va_arg(dim_list, size_t);
                assert(dimension_n > 0);
                dimensions_remaining[i] = dimension_n;
            }
        va_end(dim_list);

        smart_array <T, N - 1> temp_smart_array(dimensions_remaining);
        vec.assign(dimension_1, temp_smart_array);
    }

    smart_array<T, N - 1>& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        assert(index < vec.size() && index >= 0);
        return vec[index];
    }

    size_t length() const
    {
        return vec.size();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class smart_array<T, 1>
{
    vector <T> vec;

public:
    explicit smart_array(vector <size_t> &dimension) : vec(dimension[0])
    {
        assert(dimension[0] > 0);
    }

    explicit smart_array(size_t dimension_1 = 1) : vec(dimension_1)
    {
        assert(dimension_1 > 0);
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        assert(index < vec.size() && index >= 0);
        return vec[index];
    }

    size_t length()
    {
        return vec.size();
    }
};
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
#include "smart_array.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    // testing 1 dimension
    smart_array <int, 1> x(3);
    x[0] = 0, x[1] = 1, x[2] = 2;
    cout << "x.length(): " << x.length() << endl;

    // testing 2 dimensions
    smart_array <float, 2> y(2, 3);
    y[0][0] = y[0][1] = y[0][2] = 0;
    y[1][0] = y[1][1] = y[1][2] = 1;
    cout << "y.length(): " << y.length() << endl;
    cout << "y[0].length(): " << y[0].length() << endl;

    // testing 3 dimensions
    smart_array <char, 3> z(2, 4, 5);
    cout << "z.length(): " << z.length() << endl;
    cout << "z[0].length(): " << z[0].length() << endl;
    cout << "z[0][0].length(): " << z[0][0].length() << endl;
    z[0][0][4] = 'c'; cout << z[0][0][4] << endl;

    // testing 4 dimensions
    smart_array <bool, 4> r(2, 3, 4, 5);
    cout << "r.length(): " << r.length() << endl;
    cout << "r[0].length(): " << r[0].length() << endl;
    cout << "r[0][0].length(): " << r[0][0].length() << endl;
    cout << "r[0][0][0].length(): " << r[0][0][0].length() << endl;

    // testing copy constructor
    smart_array <float, 2> copy_y(y);
    cout << "copy_y.length(): " << copy_y.length() << endl;
    cout << "copy_x[0].length(): " << copy_y[0].length() << endl;

    cout << copy_y[0][0] << "\t" << copy_y[1][0] << "\t" << copy_y[0][1] << "\t" << 
        copy_y[1][1] << "\t" << copy_y[0][2] << "\t" << copy_y[1][2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your platform doesn't allow the standard library, what is `vector`?

Comment: You say that your BREW compiler doesn't support the C++ standard library then immediately use `vector`.  Which is it?

Comment: Your code includes some features only found in the upcoming C++0x (`static_assert`), which indicates a *very* up-to-date compiler, but you also say your compiler doesn't implement most of the library. That makes it a bit tricky to give much advice as we simply don't know what the compiler does or does not support.

Comment: @Neil, @Caspin: Sorry guys, forgot to mention that, `std::vector` will be replaced by a custom written vector that'll work in BREW (http://www.developer.com/ws/brew/article.php/2170101/Utility-Libraries-for-BREW-mdash-A-Vector-Class.htm)

Comment: @jalf: `std::vector` and `static_assert` is there because I put up the code I wrote on my desktop PC initially to design and debug the class template, so that once I perfect it (so that it can be used in non-Brew projects too), later I'll part with `static_assert` and `std::vector`; Also, another reason I used these is, it's easy for people to understand them implicitly.

Comment: @legends Believe me, writing a custom version of vector will be a thousand times more difficult than writing your smart_array. Basically, you don't have  a clue what you are doing.

Comment: @Neil: I should've been clear, by saying "custom vector impl" it'll have a very minimal implementation that'll suffice my need. Allocate contiguous space; realloc and copy old mem. when required.

Comment: However, assuming we are going to use this code on a Linux desktop machine, with all `std` available (libstdc++ and gcc), in that case, how can this be improved? Opinions/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want from this type:

In short, it would be optimal to use the form:

`template < typename T_, unsigned N_ >

struct t_array {

    /* ... */

    static const size_t Size = N_;
    typedef T_ T;

    T objects_[Size];

};`

for many reasons *if* you want only a fixed size and fixed type array. The compiler can make a lot of safe assumptions - this has reduced object size to 20% (compared to using std::vector) for me in some cases. It also faster, safer. If you use them everywhere, then you may end up creating much *larger* binaries (compared to using std::vector).

There is a class `<boost/array.hpp>` which you should read.

Sorry if you don't find that helpful - I think reading at least one common production quality implementation (before venturing into new technologies) would help.

Comment: Thanks for replying Justin. Tthe `smart_array` class deals with multiple dimensions. Thats the whole diference; what you've written uses the 2nd template parameter as a magnitude (count) for dimension 1 always, no more dimensions are allowed; whereas in the impl. I've written, the 2nd param is the number of dimensions; it's magnitude is given in the variadic constructor. I do understand that using raw arrays might be faster, but the whole point of using vector here is to avoid mess with low level arrays and their caveats like waliking off the edge, etc.

Comment: I think I get your point, having multiple dimensions is possible via std::array (in C++11, borrowed from Boost) too, even if it doesn't have enough syntatic sugar, it's more efficient than having vectors.

Comment: @legends2k right. just like you would do by declaring an array of `std::arrays` when using `std::array` for multi-dimensional arrays, you could also use this to declare a multi-dimensional array. of course, you would likely want to also give it a good/usable interface and centralized error detection.